# cakephp 3 howto add active to paginator sort class?

Tags: cakephp, bootstrap-4, cakephp-3.x

With the last release of Bootstrap, the .active property is set on the link class. How could we add this property to a Paginator->sort ?

An example :

```
$this->Paginator->templates([
    'sort' => '<a class="nav-link" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>',
]);

<ul class="nav">
  <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <?= $this->Paginator->sort('Results.points','Per points') ?>
  </li>

  <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <?= $this->Paginator->sort('Results.size','Per size') ?>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How could we add *active* to the "*Per points*" or "*Per size*" link?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current Sort param value with the following.

```
<?php $active = $this->Paginator->param('sort'); ?>
```

With that you can take and add the class on the fly for your items.

```
  <li role="presentation" class="nav-item <?= $active === 'Results.points' ? 'active' : ''; ?>
      <?= $this->Paginator->sort('Results.points','Per points') ?>
  </li>
```

Another possible option might be to override the `sortAsc` and `sortDesc` templates and wrap them with the active and wrap the standard sort template with your base `<li>` template

```
$this->Paginator->templates([
    'sort' => '<li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
    'sortAsc' => '<li role="presentation active" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
]);
```

Edit: this example is for applying my changes to the A tag.

```
$this->Paginator->templates([
    'sort' => '<li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
    'sortAsc' => '<li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks fot this answer, but it does not works with **bootstrap 4** because `active` state is set on the class of the "a" tag and not on the class of the "li" tag.

Comment: You should be able to take what I am doing and apply it the same way but in the a tag. Ill update the example for you.